# Best way to get session id in Kohana 3?

Tags: php, session, kohana, kohana-3

What is the best way to get the current visitors session id in Kohana v3? `session_id()` doesn't seem to work and only returns null for me..

At the moment Im using `cookie::get('session')`, but that doesn't work on the first time you access the site, which I need to do.

I know you could do `$this->session->id()` in Kohana v2, but that doesn't seem to exist in KO3...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you use any of these 3 session type: Native, Cookie, Database.

For cookie, I believe you don't have session id. Even if you call Session::instance()->regenerate() when using cookie as session type, it will only return NULL.

For native, you should be able to get the ID when generating it by Session::instance()->regenerate() which returns the session id.

For database, Session_Database has protected $_session_id where session id is stored. You may want to extend that class and write your own getter.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Kohana have wrapper class for sessions. That class is called Session. Kohana allows multiple ways to store session data using multiple drivers such as memcached. I am using native way to store session data, that is default if you don't make any config changes via config/session.php
I have looked kohana code for native session and found that this will give session id

```
Session::instance()->id();
```

It works for me. hope it works for you as well!

Comment: To increase the quality of your post please include how/why your answer will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Look this commit http://github.com/kohana/core/commit/f67b07a69c4e16027ac52fda7a0747c510eee164

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the source on GitHub, I can't seem to find a method for returning the id.

However, `session_id()` is used for the [native driver](http://github.com/kohana/core/blob/master/classes/kohana/session/native.php#L41), so perhaps it *should* work in your case.

Perhaps if you call `session_regenerate_id()` first?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the database driver then the cookie will hold the session id.

On the other hand it seems to be no direct way to get the session id. 
As how @SyaZ suggested, you should extend the session class and write your own getter method.